# How to disable SSL Verification in Spring Vault (Spring Vault Core - version: 2.3.1)

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-vault

I am getting below exception:

```
Cannot login using org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://<kmaas_domain>:443/v1/auth/aws/login": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
org.springframework.vault.authentication.VaultLoginException: Cannot login using org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://kmaas_domain:443/v1/auth/aws/login": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I am using VaultTemplate to acquire the Token from Kmaas (implementation on HCP Vault) to get secrets. How can I disable this SSL check? Python based Boto library does have this option as

`requests.request(request_type, RESOURCE_PATH, headers={'X-Vault-Token': client_token}, **verify=False**, data=PAYLOAD)`

but I can't find any such option in Java

Comment: Hi @dishansh, did you find any answer to this?

Comment: Instead of disabling you can follow the official guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/docs/current/reference/html/#vault.config.ssl